# Logoff from freezed remote desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access

I'm trying to logoff from a remote session to a Server where are installed all the printer of the company, the problem is that in a moment the screen turned black and I can't logoff, I can't reboot the server because it's used by other employees, I just need to know how can I logoff.

Comment: You will have to go to the physical server to solve this problem.  You might be lucky and eventually the dead lock will resolve itself.

Comment: @Ramhound It turns out that my account was freezed on that server, so I solved it accesing from another server and kicked out myself using the Terminal Service Manager tool.